# pdo always return false

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
<?php
class Group {
    private $db, $last_id;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->db = Database::connect();
    }

    public function createGroup($admin_id, $name, $description, $type) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO group SET admin_id = ?, name = ?, description = ?, type = ?";
        $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $result = $query->execute(array($admin_id, $name, $description, $type));
        if ($result) {
            $this->last_id = $this->db->lastInsertId();
            return $this->last_id;
        }
        return "false";
    }

}

?>
```

Here is my test.php :

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require "includes/database.php";
require "classes/C_Group.php";

$obj = new Group;
$result = $obj->createGroup(1, "groupName", "groupDescription", "groupType");
echo $result;
?>
```

Table screenshot :

[image]

It always returns false, i also tried insert only one parameter (name) into table, but it return false again. And nothing inserted in table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`group` is [Reserved Words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/keywords.html)  is mysql is must be in backtick

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO `group` SET admin_id = ?, name = ?, description = ?, type = ?";
```